# SQL - Find orders with certain item combo(from another table)

Tags: loops, t-sql, while-loop

I have these 3 tables - CodesetList, Rule, Order:

In the first row of the Rule table, if a client ordered any of the CODE_ID under CODESET_ID=12 and any of the CODE_ID under CODESET_ID = 7 on the same service date(DAYS_FROM_Service=0), I want to find the transaction in Order table.  Ultimately, if a client orders a combination of two items(Rule table), we want to deny the order according to the rule table.

Sorry, I'm bad at explaining this.

Rule:

[image]

CodesetList(note that ABC0274 is under Codeset_ID 9 & 10 and this is expected):

[image]

Order:

[image]

```
-- Create CodsetList table
SELECT '7' as CODESET_ID, 'ABC0210' as CODE_ID INTO #CodesetList UNION ALL
SELECT '8','ABC0220' UNION ALL
SELECT '8','ABC0230' UNION ALL
SELECT '8','ABC0240' UNION ALL
SELECT '8','ABC0250' UNION ALL
SELECT '8','ABC0260' UNION ALL
SELECT '9','ABC0270' UNION ALL
SELECT '9','ABC0272' UNION ALL
SELECT '9','ABC0274' UNION ALL
SELECT '9','ABC0273' UNION ALL
SELECT '10','ABC0274' UNION ALL
SELECT '11','ABC0277' UNION ALL
SELECT '12','ABC0330' UNION ALL
SELECT '83','ABC5110' UNION ALL
SELECT '83','ABC5120' UNION ALL
SELECT '83','ABC5130' UNION ALL
SELECT '83','ABC5140' 

-- Create Rule table
SELECT '12' as TARGET_CODESET_ID, '7' as DENIAL_CODESET_ID, '2' as DIRECTION_FROM_DOS, '0' as DAYS_FROM_Service INTO #Rule UNION ALL
SELECT '83','7','1','365' UNION ALL
SELECT '7','8','2','0' UNION ALL
SELECT '7','9','2','0' 

-- Create Order table
SELECT 'C3340' as ClientID, CAST('2019-10-12' AS DATE) as Service_Date, 'ABC0210' as CODE_ID INTO #Order UNION ALL
SELECT 'C3340',CAST('2019-10-12' AS DATE),'ABC0220' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C3340',CAST('2018-10-23' AS DATE),'ABC0272' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C3340',CAST('2019-10-09' AS DATE),'ABC0220' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C7646',CAST('2019-11-07' AS DATE),'ABC5110' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C7646',CAST('2019-05-07' AS DATE),'ABC0210' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C5376',CAST('2018-12-02' AS DATE),'ABC8411' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C5376',CAST('2018-10-18' AS DATE),'ABC8411' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C5376',CAST('2018-08-06' AS DATE),'ABC8161' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C9873',CAST('2019-01-06' AS DATE),'ABC6517' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C9873',CAST('2019-01-28' AS DATE),'ABC7784' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C9873',CAST('2019-03-05' AS DATE),'ABC8110'
```

Here's my poor attempt.

It only addresses one of the rules (row 3 from Rule table: Target=7, Denial=8)
And it also ignores  the Days_From_Service rule.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM #Order AS o
      WHERE o.CODE_ID IN(SELECT CODE_ID FROM #CodesetList WHERE CODESET_ID=7)) AS T
    INNER JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM #Order AS o
      WHERE o.CODE_ID IN(SELECT CODE_ID FROM #CodesetList WHERE CODESET_ID=8)) AS D ON T.ClientID=D.ClientID AND T.Service_Date=D.Service_Date;
```